# When reading from a file into a 2d array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, streamreader, streamwriter

I want to know how to read out of a file and display the data on different labels.
If anybody can suggest an efficient way of doing this `100` items for diffident file locations, that will appropriated .

```
 Private Sub BtnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click         If RadFriday.Checked = True Then
            Select Case Row 
                Case 0 
                    Customer(0, 0) = New StreamWriter("D:\theater seats\friday\A1Seat.txt") 
                    Customer(0, 0).Write(ArrayFS(0, 0, 0) & (" ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 1) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 2) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 3) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 4) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 5) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 6) & (", ") & ArrayFS(0, 0, 7))
                    MsgBox("Data has been stored.") 
                    Customer(0, 0).Close() 
            End Select 
  End If

    End Sub
Private Sub BtnRead_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnRead.Click 
            Select Case Row 
                Case 0 
                    LblName.Text = "" 
                    CustomerLoad(0, 0, 0) = New StreamReader("D:\theater seats\friday\A1Seat.txt")
                    LblName.Text = CustomerLoad(0, 0, 0).ReadToEnd
                    If LblName.Text = "" Then
                        MsgBox("There is no data stored for this seat!")
                    Else
                        CustomerLoad(0, 0, 0).Close()
                    End If
            End Select
        ElseIf RadSaturday.Checked = True Then

        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: basically,from a file read into different labels. Have a line in the file deterred to a to one thing like a name or a date of birth and write that data to a separable label.

Comment: Can you be more specific? A use case would help. Your code does not.

Comment: Sorry about that. What i'm trying to do is to store user input located in the arraySf and write it line by line to .txt file. From that .txt file i need to the recover all that has been write and display each separate line to  8 different labels. So each line goes to a corresponding label. the problems i ma facing are that everything at the moment is write in one line and i only know how to write the data to only one label.I need to repeat this process about a 100 times. So any about how to do that will also be appropriated.

Comment: Please be more specific. Include a sample input file and how you want to assign it to a sample set of labels. Pick the first 5, for example, just to illustrate the concept.

Comment: I am not asking about your implementation. Can you post a link to the file you keep talking about? If it's not very long, you can also post the contents here in your question. If it's very long, post, say, first 10 lines of it.

Comment: one of the forms which i need this is for has 1079 lines , the code that i'm working on at the moment is at the top